# What is this specific shell script statement validating?

Tags: linux, unix, shell-scripting, syntax

I'm not a good Shell Script expert.  Can somebody help me to understand and explain the statement `[ ! -z ${TRUE:-} ] && [ ${TRUE:-} == 'true' ] &&`from the following snippet.  What is this specific statement doing and/or being validated for?

However, am able to understand this statement: `TRUE=$($JBOSS_TWIDDLE get jboss.system:type=Server Started |grep  Started |cut -d"=" -f2)`.  This basically calling a JBoss's JMX command-line tool to check the server start status.

**Code Snippet:**

```
while [ $i -lt 180 ]; do
        TRUE=$($JBOSS_TWIDDLE get jboss.system:type=Server Started |grep  Started |cut -d"=" -f2)

        [ ! -z ${TRUE:-} ] && [ ${TRUE:-} == 'true' ] && {
    echo "The $JBOSS_NAME server is up and running."
    return
}
```

Comment: This may help: [ -z STRING ] True of the length if "STRING" is zero.

It looks like it's saying if it's not empty and it's true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @drew-khoury and @ramruma point out, the `[ -z ...` test is superfluous.

Using `TRUE` as the name of a variable just adds to the confusion.

The actual question that snippet tries to answer is: did `twiddle.sh` print `Started=true`?
Or, in shell speak:

```
jboss_is_started() {
    ($JBOSS_TWIDDLE get jboss.system:type=Server Started |
        grep 'Started=true' | read)
}
```

The `grep ... | read`  construct will return true if grep was successful, while dropping the output.

```
if jboss_is_started; then
     echo "The $JBOSS_NAME server is up and running."
     return
fi
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. `twiddle.sh` prints `Started=true`.

Answer (score 2):

The elaborate precautions against $TRUE being empty are not needed if double quotes are used.

```
[ "$TRUE" = 'true' ]
```

The -z tests if $TRUE is not empty, and :- substitutes nothing if it is unset. It is all unnecessary. Perhaps it is a protest against an over-prescriptive coding standard.